# Printable case design for Rpi 3B+

Tags: pi-3b+, case

I am looking for a proper paper printable case design for pi 3B+.

I'm talking about the latest 2018 model.  Tried searching for it online, but I only got designs for older Rpi models.

Answer (score 1):

> Tried searching for it online, but I only got designs for older Rpi models.

The B+, 2B, 3B, and 3B+ all have near identical form factors.  Most notable differences are:

- The LEDs on the 2B are in a different location, which is a factor with some cases as they may be covered up, and vice versa if you use a case designed for the 2 on a 3, etc.
- The 3B+ has beefier wifi chip in the corner next to the GPIOs; for most cases this will be irrelevant.
- The 2B has the RAM on the bottom of the board, although this is not a big deal case wise either.

Since far more 3's than 2's have been sold, most cases target the former.  Any design you find for a 3B should work for a 3B+.  To make sure, have a look at the Foundation's product pages:

- [Raspberry Pi 3B](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/)
- [Raspberry Pi 3B+](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-plus/)

There are a number of pictures there as well as mechanical drawings in PDF form (look under "Specifications").  These have the exact dimensions and should reassure you WRT case design.  The most finicky cases are probably the layered ones, which have supports that crisscross both surfaces of the board.  But a standard box case should be fine.

[This Pimoroni blog](https://blog.pimoroni.com/a-deep-dive-into-the-raspberry-pi-3-b-hardware/) has an interesting photo of the differences.  Pimoroni do some of the finnicky, intricate layered cases (that are very sexy) and hardware hats.  Hopefully they won't mind me sticking that pic in here:

[image]

The red bits are the 3B, the blue the 3B+.  The differences are not very significant, case wise.  There is also a pic of the underside in the blog, there are even fewer differences that way.